# Using Curl on windows

Tags: curl, http-post

How can i use Curl for posting data to a URL on windows platform

I tried

```
curl -d "username=test&pasword=test" http://127.0.0.1/login.aspx
```

and

```
curl -F "username=test&pasword=test" http://127.0.0.1/login.aspx
```

But its just display the html of "login.aspx", not logging in.
Please help to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
curl -u test:test http://127.0.0.1/login.aspx
```